# Footer overlaps content above it

Tags: css, footer

I sticked footer to bottom of page, but somehow it doesn't keep flow of previous element, which is now likely below (in Z axis) footer. Footer should be just lower than `.center-main` element. However that one has absolute property, cause either way it doesn't fit in center of page - when other than 'position: absolute' it is below `.cat-menu` element, BUT footer still overlaps it.

**Problematic CSS part:**

```
.cat-menu
{
    width: 20%;
    margin: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid blue;

}

.center-main
{
    width: 79%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

footer
{
    clear: both;
    border: 2px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 99.7%;
}
```

**Whole page:** https://jsfiddle.net/tnmmoLnq/1/ (those buttons at center of page are bad positioned on jsfiddle - on my PC they are ok).

Answer (score 4):

Your `fixed` footer will always be overlapping the container (unless it (the container) has a `height` set).  What you need to do is create an `outer-container` that the footer will overlap, and an `inner-container` with a `marin-bottom` the same height as your footer.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tnmmoLnq/7/)

```
.center-main-inner
{
    width: 79%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000FF;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

And here is static -- non fixed version:

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnmmoLnq/10/)

Comment: Good answer. You can also avoid nested containers by adding a bottom padding to the content container that is larger than the footer height.

Comment: ^^ Yup yup I agree .. Same concept in theory

Comment: The main issue you will encounter with fixed footers is that eventually you will probably want a responsive design and the footer height will vary depending on the width of the screen.

Comment: @Zak Thank you for solution. How could i stick `footer` to bottom without setting it's position to `fixed`? Cause in fact, eventually i am going to make whole page Responsive. 
And what if i don't want footer to be visible all time when this site will be longer (more content in `.center-section`)? I know it's because of `position: fixed` - i just want footer to stick to bottom, but not visible all time while scrolling (just put it at the and of page).

Comment: I've added another fiddle for you  --  You weren't accounting for padding and margins ...  If you have an element height of `100px` and padding of `20px` ..  The element is no longer `100px`, so the element ends up overlapping the element(s) under it because the element under/next to it "sees" it should only be `100px`.  That's why we use `margin`.  Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tnmmoLnq/10/